# Is it necessary to use 'new' operator in the following C++ code?

Tags: c++, this-pointer

The code is:

```
class base{
    base(){}
    virtual base* copy()const=0;
    virtual ~base(){}
};
class derived:public base{
    derived(){}
    base* copy()const;
    ~derived(){}
};
base* derived::copy()const{
   return new derived(*this);
}
```

Is it necessary to use the `new` operator in the function `copy()` or why the code use the `new` operator?

Should I directly return `this` pointer, like this:

```
const base* derived::copy()const{
   return this;// note: this pointer is const.
}
```

Comment: A method named copy and returning this?

Comment: Have you ever head about a copy constructor?

Comment: No, you shouldn't return `this`. The function name implies it's a new object identical but independent of the original.

Comment: One does not know, when the original `this` is deleted, it might be a stack object.

Comment: Shouldn't `derived` actually derive from `base`?

Comment: Your `derived` class doesn' derive from anything and if it *did* inherit `base`, then `base` should most likely have a virtual destructor (which it doesn't).

Comment: Your second example doesn't even compile. Doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I correct some mistakes, but this code may not be compiled

Comment: @MarianSpanik :  a copy constructor is not virtual and thus cannot be used for copying a `derived` object from a `base` pointer, which is a very common problem. The method is more often called `clone` rather than `copy`, though.

Comment: Side comment, instead of declaring the derived copy with `base* copy()const;`, you can use `derived* copy()const;`, it will properly overload the base function, and allow you returning a `derived` object when possible.

Comment: @Tong: Note: The more idiomatic name is `clone` instead of `copy`

Comment: @Tong: you're missing the point: in `derived::copy()const`, the `this` pointer is `const`. You can't return it as non-const.

Answer (score 11):

To put it **extremely** simply, no.

The `this` keyword in C++ is a small bit of syntactic sugar meaning "pointer to the current instance of this object".

A `copy` method, by English-language definition, returns a *new* object, identical to the first in every way but *occupying a different location in memory*. Returning `this` from a `copy` method would, quite naturally, break with this paradigm, because it would be returning a pointer *to the object being "copied"*.

Comment: Very nicely phrased.

Comment: @Sebastian: May I consider that returning a new object, may just because of the user's custom, right?

Answer (score -1):

your function

```
base* derived::copy()const{
   return new derived(*this);
}
```

seems to be correct - you have to use the "new" Operator here. Otherwise, you would create a local instance (of class derived) and return a pointer to that local instance. After execution of your method, the local instance will get invalid (because it is out of scope).